# Does Playwright offer clickable test suite that anybody can run through a dashboard page?

Tags: automated-testing, python, e2e, playwright

We need to implement automated E2E testing that would allow anybody on the team to visit the dashboard page and review test run reports and at the same time initiate new tests with a button click. Is this achievable through Playwright?

Comment: Have you checked Playwright's website for features they offer? Also, are you using or planning to use CI/CD tools? CI/CD allows the team to see what test suites are setup, to run them, and to see results.

Comment: Hi @LeeJensen, I did check the Playwright's website but it's not clear enough to me. We are not planning to use CI/CD tools yet. Just trying to automate the regression suites that anybody on our team can execute with a button click on-demand. Thoughts/Suggestions?

Comment: Well, I don't believe Playwright has such capability from when I've reviewed it. Essentially, your best solution is to use a CI/CD tool, even if it's only for running tests from a common place!